# How can user search existing room between an date range?

Tags: php, mysql, date, codeigniter

I want to create a search page that takes a room name, check-in, and check-out date to check if a room is available.

So if users want to search rooms for booking they must input room name, check-in date, and check-out date then click the search button.

If a room has an existing booking and the date range overlaps with the user input then it will not show, and otherwise. Now my SQL output is based on the room name only, I have no idea why it does not check for date overlaps.

```
   function search($room, $start, $end) {

      $this->db->select('  rId as id,
                           rName as name,
                           rCapacity as capacity,
                           bCheckin as checkin,
                           bCheckout as checkout,
                           bBookingTime as bookingtime
                        ');

      $this->db->from('room');
      $this->db->join('booking', 'rId = brId', 'left');
      $this->db->like('rName', $room);     
      $this->db->where('bCheckout' > $start AND 'bCheckin' < $end);
      $this->db->where('brId', NULL);
      
      return $this->db->get()->result_array();
   }
```

This the raw SQL:

```
$query = " SELECT rId as id,
                           rName as name,
                           rCapacity as capacity,
                           bCheckin as checkin,
                           bCheckout as checkout,
                           bBookingTime as bookingtime
      FROM room r
      LEFT
      JOIN booking b
         ON b.brId= r.rId
      AND NOT ( $end >= b.bCheckout OR $start<= b.bCheckin )
      WHERE r.rName = $room
      WHERE b.rbId IS NULL";
      return $this->db->query($query)->result_array();
```

[room Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar2Br.png)

[booking Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0gX7.png)

Sorry I can't show image here so I attach in above link.

Comment: Can you write your SQL query separatly? Meaning plain SQL without it being mixed in that PHP code?

Comment: @Zakk I have sparated raw SQL.

Comment: `WHERE r.rName = $room WHERE b.orderRuangan IS NULL`... should be `WHERE r.rName = $room AND b.orderRuangan IS NULL`.

Comment: But your code is very vulnerable to SQL Injection. Why don't you use prepared statements?

Comment: I am newbie, how to prepared statement?

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

Comment: Better use [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) when dealing with databases in PHP.

Comment: @Zakk that is not helpfull at all cause it seems OP is using the database framework of codeigniter - [docs](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#prepared-queries)

Comment: @Zakk yes I have used codeigniter, and have used prepared statements. FYI till now is hard to search for available room .

Comment: I think this part of the CodeIgniter query is not going to return true. $this->db->where('brId', NULL); because it results in 'brid = NULL' which doesn't return true because NULL is not equal to anything. Hope this helps

Comment: @J2112O so if I want return true, must delete this line `$this->db->where('brId', NULL);` , but query result will not return anything.

Comment: @ mark. I'm not sure how to use the Query Builder with NULL values. Maybe a good option is to write the entire SQL string as you need and make sure to escape the variables you use and use prepared statements for safer queries.

Answer (score -1):

```
$query = " SELECT r.Id as id,
                           r.Name as name,
                           r.Capacity as capacity,
                           b.Checkin as checkin,
                           b.Checkout as checkout,
                           b.BookingTime as bookingtime
      FROM room r
      LEFT
      JOIN booking b
         ON b.brId= r.rId
      WHERE
          NOT($end >= b.bCheckout OR $start<= b.bCheckout)
      AND r.rName LIKE $room
      AND b.orderRuangan IS NULL";
```

Maybe it will helpful

Comment: I got an error, `Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '>= b.bCheckout OR <= b.Checkin ) AND...' at line 12`